# After payment successful on paypal show error

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module

After complete transaction when redirect on site then show error like this[image]

How I can remove this error

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Transaction.php` is extending a file that does not exist.

Check that `Magegiant/GiantPoints/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php` exists and if not create it or remove the reference to it in `Transaction.php`.

Comment: What if I rename `Transaction.php` to `Abstract.php`?

Comment: Then whatever is using/referencing Transaction.php would break as it cannot find the Transaction.php file.

Comment: I am new in magento. So what code I need to write in Abstract.php

Comment: And I am trying Rename Transaction.php to Abstract.php then It is show error like:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getReadConnection() on a non-object in /home/content/07/6842007/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php on line 134`